A complicated sum involving Associated Laguerre Polynomials
I want to find out the closed form answer of the following summation (where, the reference of Higher transcendental functions, volume II by H Bateman, A Erdélyi is given)  such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n'=0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{e}^{-\beta E_{n'}}}{Z}\times \sqrt{\frac{n'!}{(n'+p)!}}\times\text{e}^{-x^2}\times |x|^p\times \text{L}_{n'}^p(2x^2)
\end{eqnarray}
where, $E_{n'}=(n'+1/2)\hbar \omega$, $p=1,2,3...$, $Z=\frac{1}{1-\text{e}^{-\beta\hbar\omega}}$ is the partition function, $\text{L}_{n'}^p(x^2)$ is the associated Laguerre polynomials.
I got the identity, which might be useful in this case that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{w}^{n}\frac{\text{L}_n^k(x)}{\Gamma (n+k+1)}=\text{e}^{w}\times (xw)^{-\frac{k}{2}}\times\text{J}_k(2\sqrt{xw})$$
where, $w=\text{e}^{-\beta \hbar \omega}$ as per the above problem, but there is an extra factor in the question i.e. $\sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}}$, which is not found in the identity.
Would you kindly help me to findout the result of the summation.

The darn square root is for normalization of the associated Laguerre polynomials I was trying to figure out if this is a Laguerre-Fourier series of some function but I'm not sure. Do you know if the identity with the modified bessel function that you edited was true or just a conjecture?

Thanks for your reply....In page number 102 of the book of ORTHOGONAL POLYNOMIALS BY GABOR SZEGO, PROFESSOR OF MATHEMATICS, STANFORD UNIVERSITY (free version of which is available in google) the identity nummber 1.15 and 1.16 may kindly be seen. This is the identity, what I wrote before.

Is the argument inside the Laguerre polynomials supposed to be $x^2$ or $2x^2$?

@
Hug de Roda, you can consider the argument inside Laguerre function as x^2 then the arguemnt of exp will be Exp (x^2/2)
